# How can I create a vertical line in a drawable xml? Android

Tags: android, line, android-drawable

Is there a way to make a drawable that draws a vertical line? So far I have a horizontal line that draws this:

[image]

current code is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/object_switcher_background" />
    <item android:left="0dp"
          android:right="250dp">
        <shape android:shape="line">

            <stroke android:color="@color/c19"
                android:width="2dp"/>
            <size android:width="40dp"/>
        </shape>

    </item>
    <item android:left="50dp"
          android:bottom="50dp"
          android:top="75dp"
          android:right="150dp">
          <shape android:shape="line">

              <stroke android:color="@color/c19"
                  android:width="2dp"
                  android:rotation="90"/>
              <size android:width="40dp"/>
          </shape>

    </item>
</layer-list>
```

How can I manipulate this to make it look like this?

[image]

Comment: check [this](https://github.com/mohit008/Android-Geomatry-Figure)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this by nesting your second item inside a `rotate` item.

Comment: hmm ya I understand thats an option I just don't understand exactly how the `rotate` works... would you have an example?

Answer (score 2):

you can do that using rotate item: the below code defines a white background with a vertical divider using only xml drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <rotate android:fromDegrees="90">
            <shape android:shape="line">
                <stroke
                    android:width="1dp"
                    android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure why you need a drawable for this.

This can also be done by using a simple view and adjusting its height, width and position according to your needs. For example:

```
 <View
      android:layout_width="1dp"
      android:background="@color/grey_text_color"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```